# Android Malware Static Analysis - Androguard

Tags: android, permissions, static, malware-detection, androguard

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.10/codeop.py in **call**(self, source, filename, symbol)
116
117     def **call**(self, source, filename, symbol):
--> 118         codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, True)
119         for feature in _features:
120             if codeob.co_flags & feature.compiler_flag:

TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module

Example link:
https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/english/33093-introduction-to-android-malware-analysis.pdf

androguard link:
https://androguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/gettingstarted.html

I am currently researching the use of Androguard for Android malware static analysis. I am trying to analyze a malware using an example from the following link, and I want to retrieve the permissions and API calls from the file. However, when I use the following syntax: "a, d, dx = AnalyzeAPK("file path")", the error mentioned above occurs. How can I solve this? Thank you.

system:
Ubuntu 22.04.1
python 3.10.6